# If statement syntax error (BASH)

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

I'm trying to get the disk usage of some sites on a server using the script below, but I'm getting this error whenever I try to run it:

```
args.sh: line 50: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
args.sh: line 50: `fi'
```

I can't see any syntax errors, but I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="/var/www/html/"
suffix=".example.com"
path="$prefix$1$suffix"
args_length="$#"
paths_array=[]
args_array=("$@")

# If there is one argument, calculate disk usage of given site.
if [ args_length -eq 1];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage..."
    output=$(du -sh $path)
    echo "This site is currently using $output"
    exit 1

# If there are no arguments, calculate disk usage of all sites.
elif [ args_length -lt 1];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage for all sites..."
    # I haven't done this part yet!
    exit 1

# If there is more than one site, calculate their disk usage    
elif [ args_length > 1];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage for selected sites..."    
    #Save arguments to sites_array
    for x in args_array; do
        paths_array[x] = args_array[x]
    done
    #Loop through array, creating paths.
    for i in paths_array; do
        site = paths_array[i]
        paths_array[i] = "$prefix$site$suffix"
    done
    #Print out disk usage for each path in array.
    for y in paths_array; do
        output = $(du -sh $paths_array[y]) 
        echo "This site is currently using $output"
fi
```

Side Note: For the section that I haven't written yet, can anyone tell me how I should go about saving the names of all the folders in the current working directory to an array? I've heard that parsing the output of 'ls' is a bad idea, so I'm looking for an alternative to that if anyone has one.

Comment: You are missing spaces before your closing `]` in those `[` tests. You are also missing a final `done` in that last block. Run your code through http://shellcheck.net to find these (and other issues). You also aren't looping over the array contents with `for y in paths_array` that just loops over the string `paths_array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is *really* close - you just have a few different small syntax errors in play here.

The syntax errors:

1. You weren't closing your last `for` loop with `done` - hence the syntax error on `fi`: the interpretor was thinking it was still in the loop.
2. You dropped the `$` at the beginning of the variable names in the `if` statements (e.g. `args_length` vs `$args_length`. As a result, bash is interpreting that as a string - *args length* - instead of the value of the `args_length` variable.
3. You were putting spaces around `=`. In bash, when you assign a value to a variable, there can't be spaces around `=`. Instead, it should always be like: `name="value"`.
4. You were missing spaces before your closing brackets (`]`) in your `if` statements.

This code works:

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix="/var/www/html/"
suffix=".example.com"
path="$prefix$1$suffix"
args_length="$#"
paths_array=[]
args_array=("$@")

# If there is one argument, calculate disk usage of given site.
if [ $args_length -eq 1 ];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage..."
    output=$(du -sh $path)
    echo "This site is currently using $output"
    exit 1

# If there are no arguments, calculate disk usage of all sites.
elif [ $args_length -lt 1 ];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage for all sites..."
    # I haven't done this part yet!
    exit 1

# If there is more than one site, calculate their disk usage    
elif [ $args_length -gt 1 ];
    then echo "Calculating disk usage for selected sites..."    
    #Save arguments to sites_array
    for x in args_array; do
        paths_array[x]=$args_array[x]
    done
    #Loop through array, creating paths.
    for i in paths_array; do
        site=$paths_array[i]
        $paths_array[i]="$prefix$site$suffix"
    done
    #Print out disk usage for each path in array.
    for y in paths_array; do
        output=$(du -sh $paths_array[y]) 
        echo "This site is currently using $output"
    done
fi
```

Which outputs:

```
Calculating disk usage for all sites...
```

These sorts of errors in bash are really common and can be hard to pin down, so when they occur just take it one step at a time, reread your code, and try to understand the errors you're getting.

Comment: What `-eq` and `-lt` issues did you see? The only problems I see on those lines are the spacing problem and the missing `$` to actually use the variable contents. I actually disagree that `[[` is safer **especially** in the context of numerical tests. The behavior of `[[` with numerical tests is **highly** surprising as far as I'm concerned. For example the tests here went from throwing an error (`[ args_length -lt 1 ]`) to silently comparing the value `0` against the right-hand side of the expression `[[ args_length -lt ` ]]`. That's not "safer" or "less surprising" to me.

Comment: @EtanReisner you're totally right - thanks! I missed that, and `[[` was letting that fail silently. Edited my answer. And interesting point about `[[` being *less* safe - I think I agree now...

Comment: In general `[[` **is** safer. I agree with that for the most part. It just happens that specifically with numeric tests it has a, to my mind, **very** peculiar and unfortunate behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!
Can anyone help me with the request at the end of my post?

Comment: No problem @Thorium! Regarding the second request - it's probably neater if you ask it as a second question, since you'll get more focused responses and then in the future, others can more easily search for that exact issue.

Comment: @Thorium `dirarr=(*); declare -p dirarr`